# using basic build-in or standard function(s) to solve problems in racket?

Tags: racket

I'm working with lists in Racket, and I was doing a function to sum the elements of a list.

for example

```
(define (mysum L)
(if (empty? L) 0
  (+ (first L) (mysum (rest L))))
)
```

then the result will be

```
> (mysum'(5 4))
9
>
```

But I would like to know what to do to multiply the numbers inside the list, rather than add them. when I put the * sign instead of + then it gives me an output of zero.

```
(define (myproduct L)
(if (empty? L) 0
  (* (first L) (myproduct (rest L))))
)
```

and the result is

```
> (myproduct'(3 5))
0
> enter code here
```

I'm trying to understand how to multiply numbers in a list.

Comment: Ask yourself, if `mysum` is applied to a list with just one element, how does it work?  So if `myproduct` is given a one-element list, what should it do?

Answer (score 2):

The `myproduct` should use `1` instead of `0` in the base case, because the [identity element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element) of multiplication is `1`.

```
(define (myproduct L)
  (if (empty? L) 1
      (* (first L) (myproduct (rest L)))))

> (myproduct'(3 5))
15
```

Answer (score 1):

A nice way to think about this is that `*` and `+` are the two operations of the [field of numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)).  And in any field, the two operations have identities, which are objects such that `(<op> x <identity-of-op>)` is `x`.  But they have *different* identities.  So let's define a function which tells us what the identity of the two operations is:

```
(define (identity-of op)
  (cond
    [(eqv? op +)
     0]
    [(eqv? op *)
     1]
    [else
     (error "there are only two operations for the field of numbers")]))
```

And now we can define a general function which, given an operator, will return a function which combines a bunch of numbers using it (this function will be correct, since both `*` and `+` are associative):

```
(define (make-combiner op)
  (define id (identity-of op))
  (define (combiner numbers)
    (if (null? numbers)
        id
        (op (first numbers) (combiner (rest numbers)))))
  combiner)
```

And now:

```
(define sum-numbers (make-combiner +))

(define multiply-numbers (make-combiner *))
```